# Fetch Google Analytics Data from Multiple Websites - Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-analytics

Hi I'm using [Spatie Laravel Analytics](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics)
for fetching data from the Google Analytics. Now what I need is I want to fetch data for multiple websites to my database. So do I need to make separate applications and get separate *client key* and *service account* from [Console Developers Google](https://console.developers.google.com/) for each and every website? Please let me know the best solution for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using core reporting API/oAuth, will not need additional client keys.  But for each GA Account you would need to authenticate.  One way around this last part is to share the GA access with a single account.  This way you would only need to authenticate one account.  More info: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en

Comment: @MSchenkel yes I'm using core reporting API/oAuth and each Time I need to change the SITE ID also known as client ID, something like this ga:xxxxxxxx and can use the same Service Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"service email" Sounds like you are using a service account.  You can use the same service account for them all you just have to give the service account access to all of the accounts you want to extract from.

If you are using Oauth2 then assuming that who ever authenticated the application has access to all of the websites you want to extract from then you have access to them already with the same refresh token.

Comment: Yes Sorry, I meant to say Service Account. And yes as you said I can use same service account for all of them and it worked. Only I was giving wrong Site ID: which looks something like this ga:xxxxxxxx. Only need to change that everytime.